# csv import into an Oracle table - Invalid number error

Tags: oracle, csv

I have a csv with 30k rows and 40 columns. During the import, for some rows, I get "invalid number" error.

Here is the "insert into" sample of the error row:

```
--ORA-01722: invalid number

INSERT INTO CHEM_CONTINUOUS (API, WELL_FACILITY, INJ_POINT_LOCATION, CHEMICAL_PRODUCT, PRODUCT_CATEGORY, SOLUBILITY_CONT, BASE_UNIT_PRICE, PPM_TARGET, TARGET_QPD, ADJUSTED_TARGET_QPD, TARGET_GPD, BOPD, BWPD, MSCFD, TANK_SIZE, DAYS_INVENTORY_LEFT, ACTUAL_PPM_VENDORGIVEN, ACTUALUSAGE_GALPERMONTH, TARGETUSAGE_GALPERMONTH, VARIANCE_GALPERMONTH, TARGETVARIANCE, VARIANCE_PERCENTAGE, ACTUALCOST_MONTH, TARGETCOST_WEEK, VARIANCECOST_MONTH, BEGIN_INV, DELIVERY1, DELIVERY2, DELIVERY3, END_INV, RUN_DAYS, BEG_DATE, END_DATE, ACTUAL_GAL_DAY, COMMENTS, ACTION_TAKEN, CHEMICAL_COMPANY, APPLICATION_METHOD, TEMPDATE, REFERENCEXLSHEET) VALUES ('','CRCU-1124','BACKSIDE ANNULUS','CORR11071A','Corrosion','TF',15.5,20.0,1.23312,2.0,0.5,50.0,317.0,NULL,75.0,90.0,12.12121212,10.0,16.5,-6.5,1.25,-0.393939394,155.0,255.75,-100.75,55.0,NULL,NULL,NULL,45.0,33.0,to_date('26-Jun-19'),to_date('29-Jul-19'),0.303030303,'','','Nalco','Continuous',to_date('1-Jul-19'),'');
```

Here is the table as defined in the database:

```
Name                    Null Type          
----------------------- ---- ------------- 
API                          VARCHAR2(14)  
WELL_FACILITY                VARCHAR2(100) 
INJ_POINT_LOCATION           VARCHAR2(100) 
CHEMICAL_PRODUCT             VARCHAR2(100) 
PRODUCT_CATEGORY             VARCHAR2(100) 
SOLUBILITY_CONT              VARCHAR2(100) 
BASE_UNIT_PRICE              NUMBER(11,2)  
PPM_TARGET                   NUMBER(11,2)  
TARGET_QPD                   NUMBER(11,2)  
ADJUSTED_TARGET_QPD          NUMBER(11,2)  
TARGET_GPD                   NUMBER(11,2)  
BOPD                         NUMBER(11,2)  
BWPD                         NUMBER(11,2)  
MSCFD                        NUMBER(11,2)  
TANK_SIZE                    NUMBER(11,2)  
DAYS_INVENTORY_LEFT          NUMBER(11,2)  
ACTUAL_PPM_VENDORGIVEN       NUMBER(11,2)  
ACTUALUSAGE_GALPERMONTH      NUMBER(11,2)  
TARGETUSAGE_GALPERMONTH      NUMBER(11,2)  
VARIANCE_GALPERMONTH         NUMBER(11,2)  
TARGETVARIANCE               NUMBER(11,2)  
VARIANCE_PERCENTAGE          NUMBER(11,2)  
ACTUALCOST_MONTH             NUMBER(11,2)  
TARGETCOST_WEEK              NUMBER(11,2)  
VARIANCECOST_MONTH           NUMBER(11,2)  
BEGIN_INV                    NUMBER(11,2)  
DELIVERY1                    NUMBER(11,2)  
DELIVERY2                    NUMBER(11,2)  
DELIVERY3                    NUMBER(11,2)  
END_INV                      NUMBER(11,2)  
RUN_DAYS                     NUMBER(11,2)  
BEG_DATE                     DATE          
END_DATE                     DATE          
ACTUAL_GAL_DAY               NUMBER(11,2)  
COMMENTS                     VARCHAR2(200) 
ACTION_TAKEN                 VARCHAR2(200) 
CHEMICAL_COMPANY             VARCHAR2(50)  
APPLICATION_METHOD           VARCHAR2(50)  
TEMPDATE                     DATE          
REFERENCEXLSHEET             VARCHAR2(200)
```

I am really baffled where the issue in the data is. Any idea?

Comment: there's no error with your sample row insert, but your error suggests that you're trying to insert non-numeric data to number(11,2) columns.

Comment: Please **edit your question** using the `edit` button just below the tags and include the **exact text** of the error message. It should be something like `ORA-xxxxx blah blah blah blah blah`. It's all important and we need to know exactly what it says. Thanks.

Comment: I found the error to be an extra space in one of the cells. thnx. got it fixed by checking ISnumber() for all cells.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The declaration NUMBER(11,2) says that your number has only 2 decimal places but you are inserting a number -0.393939394 which has more than two decimal places.I think this may be the source of your error